# Does changing a django models related_name attribute require a south migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a simple django model with a ForeignKey

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo', related_name="foo_choices")
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The related_name attribute exists already, but I'd like to change it. Will this change require a migration of any kind? When I run the schemamigration management command after modifying the related_name I get the "Nothing seems to have changed" but I wanted to verify.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*As mentioned in the comments, this answer is true for very old Django versions*

---

**No** You do not need a migration.

[Related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one (the reverse relationship).

`related_name` has nothing to do with the database. It is consumed by the Django's ORM to fetch queryset results, so you dont need a migration if you change the `related_name` attribute on a models' field.

Some [additional documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) on the usage of `related_name`

Comment: Then why does Django create a migration file when related_name changes?

Comment: @MarshallX This ticket may shed light on your question https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25601 . But I am still wonder there is a way to mark such migrations should not emit any sql(sqlmigrate) when only related_name is changed.

Comment: here is the code
first drop:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3a98224e6dd5f8846008512f281e452dc3b1909/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L514
then rebuild: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3a98224e6dd5f8846008512f281e452dc3b1909/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L734

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong! Yes, you need a migration. MigrationAutodetector will detect a migration.

Answer (score 12):

The above accepted answer is now outdated.

Django does create and `alter field foreign_key_field on model` migration when the related name of a foreign key field changes.

Comment: I believe it also causes, at least in MySQL, a DROP INDEX and then CREATE INDEX statement. There's an issue open in Django's issue tracker about this. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25253