# Generally, when does Django model change require South?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I am new to Django. I have completed the tutorial and am reading the documentation for more learning. As I try to add to my understanding, say, in new Managers or ModelForms I am curious as to what needs South (or even just scrapping it and rewriting the app).

[update django database to reflect changes in existing models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985383/update-django-database-to-reflect-changes-in-existing-models)

The link above says basically that any column change it is necessary, while the link below is more of what I am asking. Can someone generalize when it is not needed (eg: Adding a new Form/ModelForm based on an existing Model? Adding a Manager?) If no changes are made to the columns of the database South is not then not necessary?

[Does changing a django models related_name attribute require a south migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800115/does-changing-a-django-models-related-name-attribute-require-a-south-migration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of south migrations: schema and data.

Data migrations are used to change data in the DB and not the schema of the DB.

The schema migrations are the ones you are interested in. They are used to keep track of changes to the DB schema and one should accompany any changes to your models that result in DB schema change (create table, drop table, drop column, change null constrain e.g.)

Some great insights might be found if you read two consecutive migrations for a django app.
In each of them you can find code that applies the migreation, code that reverts the migrations and a snapshot of the DB schema.

P.S. It is quite easy to check if south migration is needed for a particular change in your models. Just run a schemamigration for the modified django app and delete the newly created migration if such was created. As creating a south migration is different that running it, this is a great way to test and learn.

Keep in mind that south is a piece of software like any other and it does 'support' bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Related_name attribute changes only affect your project and django uses it to make queries.

Changes like blank = True/False, null = True/False, symmetrical = True/False require database changes although symmetrical = True/False does not trigger update by south, but the setting definitely makes difference at field creation.

Column changes, like the link in your post shows, require updates in database and that's what south does very good.